# Data is not inserted on mobile device but works on desktop - Codeigniter and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I was trying to parse data to my controller so I can insert it into the database using JQuery and it was returning null. It's for a review star system so doesn't use conventional form fields however the network tab in inspect elements shows that data is actually posted to the controller just, not able to read it for some weird reason.

Update: The data is being inserted fine on desktop however the confirmation (flashdata) message is shown correctly not sure why. Additionally on mobile view no data or message is shown. Does anyone know why? I have updated the code below..

Here's the code from my view:

```
    <?php  if($this->session->flashdata('review_submitted')){  ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible container show" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <strong>Thank you!</strong> Your review has been submitted.
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">

<br>
            <div class="form-group text-left div-style">
             <h3 style="font-family: MontserratLight;letter-spacing: 2px; line-height: 32px;">Full Name <b>*</b></h3>
                <input name="name" class="form-control" style="background: #f7f7f7;  border: 1px solid #801424;" required />
            </div>

    <div class="rate">
        <div id="1" class="btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="2" class="btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="3" class="btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="4" class="btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="5" class="btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
</div>

  <script>
   $(function(){
 $('.rate-btn').hover(function(){
 $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
    var therate = $(this).attr('id');
    for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
 $('.btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
     };
   });

 $('.rate-btn').click(function(){
    var therate = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataRate = 'rate='+therate; //
 $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-active');
    for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
 $('.btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
    };
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
  var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/reviews/add_review";
//  $('#myForm').append(therate);
  var dataPost = $('#myForm').serialize() + "&rate=" + therate;
 $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data: dataPost,
    success:function(){

   }
  });
});
});
 });
  </script>
```

and using the controller I simply use the following to get the data and add it to the database:

```
   public function add_review(){

$name = $this->input->post('name');
$rating = $this->input->post('rate');


$dataDB = array(
  'full_name' => $name,
  'rating' => $rating
);

if($this->functions->submit($dataDB)){
  $this->session->set_flashdata('review_submitted', true);
  redirect(base_url() . 'reviews/index', 'refresh');
  }

 }
```

Here's some CSS that I used, perhaps the problem is to do with the mobile browser not having a cursor?

```
.rate{
    width:245px; height: 40px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
 .rate .rate-btn{
    width: 45px; height:40px;
   float: left;
   background: url(rate-btn.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor:hand;
    pointer-events: auto;

   }
  .rate .rate-btn:hover, .rate  .rate-btn-hover, .rate  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(rate-btn-hover.png) no-repeat;
   }
```

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Run your app in Chrome developer tools, set a breakpoint at `$.ajax({...})`and verify the URL (generated by PHP) is correct.  2) Enable CI logging and verify your controller is getting called, and called with the correct arguments, 3) Finally, after doing this, determine exactly WHAT is going wrong (*what* in your "var_dump" is null?  Is "data" null in your Ajax call?), and exactly WHERE (Client Javascript or server PHP?).  Please post back what you find.

Comment: The controller seems to be getting called. Data in the ajax call is not null and appears to hold the correct value. I've set two var_dumps one for $rating which returns null and another for $dataDB for which the field ['rating'] returns null and the other seem to have values. Data after the breakpoint is `data: "rate=3"`

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is when your PHP tries to read the POST data.  Note that you're sending "text" (not, for example, "JSON" text).  Show us your controller code.  Or better, see if you can reproduce the problem with an [MCVE].  Whatever you do - please update your original post with any/all relevant information.

Comment: The controller code is at the bottom. I removed the "text".Here's the log message `data = "string(4) "rate"↵array(2) {↵    ["rating"]=>↵  string(1) "3"↵  ["review_text"]=>↵  NULL↵}↵"`

Comment: You are creating a query string with `var dataRate = 'act=rate&post_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>&rate='+therate;` I think you should be creating an object instead  for `ajax.data`. e.g. `{post_id: <?= $post_id;?>, rate: therate }`

Comment: I don't see where the javascript gets the `review` text. Please [edit] you answer to include that.

Comment: Do you really want `$('#myForm').on('submit'...` nested inside the `$('.rate-btn').click(...` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing data through ajax, I think it is better to use JSON dataType. Reform the data type (string -> data object). Besides, I don't think it is really necessary to concat the 'to-be-sent' data into a string.

If you want dynamic data to be sent, you can push elements by condition

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType: 'text' //it is not necessary if you are not returning any data (if you return json, put 'JSON'),
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/reviews/add_review",
    data: dataRate, //change to {key:value,key:value}
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way around it last night by serializing for the form data and concatenating the rating to it using a key:value approach (pretty much). I then POST the data from the entire form using this rather than using the php post method and wallah. I've updated my original code if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to address your issue with your AJAX Posted Values not appearing where you are expecting them ONLY.

There are a zillion ways you can code this but here is just one which I have changed about to perform debugging. Even I learned a new trick doing this.

Just Nit Picking but what stuck out when reading your code is your use of `therate` when everywhere else in your JS you use camel case so it should be **theRate**.It's a good idea to choose a standard and stick to it.

Plus you had what appeared to be nested events in your JS. Some attempt at getting theRate to work correctly? Anyway...

**First things.** Get back to something basic and work your way back up. (Although in this case I didn't strip your view back to bare bones, but I did with your controller.

**Your View.**
I had to change this up a bit and hopefully the comments explain things.

I called it **rating_view.php**

```
<form name="my-form" id="my-form">
    <div class="rate">
        <div id="1" class="btn-1 rate-btn">1</div>
        <div id="2" class="btn-2 rate-btn">2</div>
        <div id="3" class="btn-3 rate-btn">3</div>
        <div id="4" class="btn-4 rate-btn">4</div>
        <div id="5" class="btn-5 rate-btn">5</div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<!-- Added for viewing debug response -->
<div id="json-debug-output"></div>

<!-- Some styles added as non were provided -->
<style>
    .rate-btn-hover {
        background: blue;
    }
    .rate-btn-active {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
<script src= <?= base_url('assets/js/jquery_v3.4.1.js'); ?>></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Define your Dom Elements ONCE for efficiency etc
        let domRateButton = $('.rate-btn');
        let domMyForm = $('#my-form');
        let theRate = 0; // Declares this as a Global Var.

        let domJsonDebugOutput = $('#json-debug-output');

        // Hover
        domRateButton.hover(function () {
            domRateButton.removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
            let theRate = $(this).attr('id');
            for (let i = theRate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.btn-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
            }
        });

        // Click
        domRateButton.click(function () {
            console.log('Rating Button Clicked');
            theRate = $(this).attr('id');
            domRateButton.removeClass('rate-btn-active');
            for (let i = theRate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.btn-' + i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
            }
        });

        // Submit
        domMyForm.on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // This was missing
            console.log('Posting Rate = ' + theRate);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // dataType: 'text',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reviews/add_review",
                data: {'act': 'rate', 'post_id':<?= $post_id; ?>, 'rate': theRate},

                success: function (data) {
                    let debugData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    domJsonDebugOutput.text(debugData); // Display in our Debug Div
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    let debugData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    domJsonDebugOutput.text(debugData); // Display in our Debug Div
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note in the AJAX the changes to **dataType** from **text** to **json**. Also note that **data is an array**.

I also changed the scope of theRate from local to a global so it was "findable" amongst the functions.

NOT SURE how your form was setup but I added e.preventDefault(); to prevent the form submitting for testing.

Personally I cringe at having PHP vars embedded in any JS code and I usually have my JS as external files and pass in the values from PHP by reading them using JS but that's got it's Pros and Cons as well. So I left that alone for the sake of not going too far with this.

**For your Controller - Called Reviews.php**

```
public function show() {
    $data['post_id'] = 1; // This comes from somewhere
    $content = $this->load->view('rating_view', $data, TRUE);
    echo $content;
}

/**
 * Called by AJAX
 * Do we need to test this is only called by AJAX?
 */
public function add_review() {
    // Return everything that was sent for debugging
    echo json_encode($this->input->post());
//      var_dump($this->input->post());
    exit();
}
```

So here I just had a method show() show the form and the add_review to simply bounce back what was sent. You can do all sorts of things with this. One nice aspect in this case is you do not need to use console.log) as you can view it all on the page (BUT ONLY FOR DEBUGGING). It's another option.

So have a play with that and start making changes to your code and see what works. Remember - get back to basics and pick on the bit that isn't working.

Next you will find you might be getting tripped up on your redirect. But that's for another post.

Comment: Thank you a tonne for this response. i actually managed to solve the issue myself. Turns out the problem was sleep deprivation. Was a simple fix I was racking my brain around for no reason although in terms of debugging etc I learnt quite a bit from this so cheers! - The solution is in the original post now.

Comment: hey again, so everything seems to be working fine except on desktop view the confirmation (flashdata) message is not shown but the data is indeed inserted into the database and on mobile view nothing happens (no data is inserted and there's no message, just a page refresh but the data is appended to the URL so its a little confusing) - I have updated the initial post.. I think it may be something to do with using buttons for stars and the cursor css with the mobile not having a cursor? - Any help is appreciated.